# Como animar una imagen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*Como puedo animar una imagén, tengo una flecha en **png**, y me gustaría animarla con **css3 o javascript**, estoy estudiando las transiciones,transformaciones,etc, pero aún no sé como. Se me ocurre hacerlo con **javascript**, con un ciclo for vaya cambiando su posición, pero este `ciclo for` se reiniciara a cada rato para que no se deje de mover la flecha y **eso sería mucho gasto de memoria**, entonces **como debo hacerlo**?*

Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes hacerlo sólo con HTML/CSS. Te puedes inspirar en [alguno de estos ejemplos](https://codepen.io/tag/animated%20arrow/) publicados en Codepen.

Comment: Estudia las animaciones, es batante facil hacerlo con eso

Answer (score 2):

```css
#imagen{
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: sBote;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes sBote{
  from{
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  to{
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="imagen" src="http://depng.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Abajo-5.png" width="100" />
```

.

Comment: que es sBote ??

Comment: Es solamente el nombre de la animación, puedes poner cualquier nombre pero tienes que modificarlo también en la propiedad "animation-name".

Answer (score 0):

Una opcion seria usar `setInterval` para que sea un ciclo infinito

```js
var div = document.getElementById('node');


setInterval(function(){
  div.innerHTML==='imagen'? div.innerHTML='flecha':div.innerHTML='imagen';
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id='node'>imagen Flecha</div>
```